# NodeJS package installation - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

Tried to install node package:

`npm install nodemon`

but it is failing with:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: nodemon@latest
```

What should I do to fix it?

```
npm -v
6.5.0

node -v
v10.13.0
```

I tried `npm cache verify` and `npm cache clean --force` but still giving the same error.

Comment: You can see I tried that already..

Comment: this may be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657560/npm-install-gives-unauthorized-name-or-password-is-incorrect-error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36690156/4694757

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by searching different forums..

Need to check first if I am logged in `npm whoami` (for me was giving error).

Then checked `/Users/myuser/.npmrc` for any strange lines and passwords.

Then did `npm login` (I never tried login before). This forced me to enter username/pass (which I do not have) and it seems it created user/pass on the fly. After 'logging in' - it worked without issues.