# Why npm install is not working only when I try to install fontawsome/free-brands-svg-icons?

Tags: reactjs, terminal, icons, font-awesome, npm-install

My npm install is working for everything else except @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons .
(I am working in React.js)
Any idea what is the problem?

**I put in the terminal this**:

npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons

**And the full message that I get from terminal is:**

npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-03-05T20_01_39_637Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Have you tried those:<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114659/npm-err-code-e401-npm-err-incorrect-or-missing-password <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657560/npm-install-gives-unauthorized-name-or-password-is-incorrect-error

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed the issue just by deleting the .npmrc file that was located in C:\Users\{your user name or ID}